# Is Android Studio code the same as in Eclipse ADT?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

Since there aren't full in depth tutorials for Android Studio yet, I am just wondering if I can follow tutorials made for Eclipse in my Android Studio projects. I am new to programming so I would appreciate if you can answer this. I like the layout of Android Studio a lot better than Eclipse ADT. So can I follow the tutorials safely or will I run into errors when following the code? I plan on following thenewboston, would I be able to efficiently use the code displayed in his videos in Android Studio even though he is using Eclipse? What tutorials would you suggest I follow?

Comment: Anroid Studio is really based on IntelliJ IDEA IDE. You can find lots of information about IDEA on web.

Answer (score 1):

You will find it easier to follow tutorials written for the IDE you are using. Android and Java will stay the same though.